# Limit of a recursive sequence

Tags: real-analysis, recurrence-relations

Let $\lambda$$\in$$(0,1)$. For any real $a_0$, $a_1$, define the sequence recursively by $$a_n = (1-\lambda)a_{n-1}  + \lambda a_{n-2}$$

Let $\alpha$ = $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n$

Express the $\alpha$ in terms of $\lambda$, $a_0$ and $a_1$

Comment: You were almost there.  If you enclose the mathematics in dollar signs $\$ ...\$$ then it gets TeXed.  You can also right click to see the source of the TeX if you want to get better at it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20942/deriving-formulas-for-recursive-functions/20943#20943). For your recurrence, the characteristic equation is $$m^2 - (1- \lambda)m - \lambda = 0$$ Rearranging we get $$m^2 - m + \lambda (m-1) = m(m-1) + \lambda (m-1) = (m+\lambda)(m-1)= 0$$ This gives us $m = 1$ (or) $m = \lambda$. The solution is then given by $a_n = c_1 + c_2 (-\lambda)^n$. Since $\lambda \in (0,1)$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = c_1$. Hence, we need to find $c_1$. Setting $n=0$, we get $a_0 = c_1 + c_2$ and $a_1 = c_1 - \lambda c_2$. Solving for $c_1$, we get $\displaystyle c_1 = \frac{\lambda a_0 + a_1}{1+ \lambda}$. Hence, $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = \frac{\lambda a_0 + a_1}{1+ \lambda}.$$

Answer (score 8):

It is important to become acquainted with the characteristic equation method. 
However, since this problem seems to come from an analysis course, and not a combinatorics course, we will solve it without using the characteristic equation machinery.

We first describe some geometric preliminaries, though in fact *none* of the geometry is used in the solution!  But it is always good to *see* what is really going on.

**Geometric preliminaries:**   If $p$ and $q$ are numbers, or indeed points in the plane or in space, and $0<\lambda<1$, then $\lambda p +(1-\lambda)q$ is the point on the ray that goes from $p$ to $q$, and divides that ray in the ratio $\lambda:1-\lambda$. In particular, $\lambda p +(1-\lambda)q$ is between $p$ and $q$ if $0 <\lambda<1$. The case $a_0=a_1$ is uninteresting, since then $a_n=a_0$ for all $n$.

Draw a picture. Without loss of generality we may assume that  $a_0<a_1$.  A little playing will show that the sequence $a_0, a_2, a_4, \dots$ is increasing, and the sequence $a_1,a_3,a_5,\dots$ is decreasing. Also, $a_{2k}<a_{2k+1}$.

The sequence $(a_{2k})$ is increasing and bounded above, so has a limit. Similarly, the sequence $(a_{2k+1})$ is bounded below, and therefore has a limit. We show that the gap between successive $a_i$ goes to $0$ has $i$ goes to infinity. That will show that the limits of $(a_{2k})$ and $(a_{2k+1})$ are the same.

The equation
$$a_n=(1-\lambda)a_{n-1}+\lambda a_{n-2}$$
can be rewritten as
$$a_n-a_{n-1}=-\lambda(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}). \qquad\text{(Equation 1)}$$
Let $c=a_1-a_0$.

Then, by Equation $1$, $a_2-a_1=-\lambda(a_1-a_0)=c(-\lambda)$. Therefore, by Equation $1$, $a_3-a_2=-\lambda(a_2-a_1)=c(-\lambda)^2$.

But $a_4-a_3=-\lambda(a_3-a_2)=c(-\lambda)^3$.  And from that we obtain $a_5-a_4=c(-\lambda)^4$.  The pattern is obvious. We have
$$a_{n}-a_{n-1}=c(-\lambda)^{n-1}. \qquad\text{(Equation 2)} $$
As $n \to \infty$, $\lambda^{n-1}\to 0$, so the gap between $a_{n-1}$ and $a_n$ goes to $0$.  It follows that the limits of $(a_{2k})$ and $(a_{2k+1})$ are the same, so we know now that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists.

**The solution:** We will use *none* of material in the geometric preliminaries, except for Equation $1$, which is not really geometric.

We can rewrite Equation $1$ as
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+c(-\lambda)^{n-1}.$$

So $a_n$ is obtained by adding $c(-\lambda)^{n-1}$ to $a_{n-1}$. A familiar procedure, the one that produces a *geometric series*! 
We have $a_1=a_0+ c$, and therefore $a_2=a_0+c+c(-\lambda)$, and therefore $a_3=a_0+c +c(-\lambda)+c(-\lambda)^2 $, and so on. In general, for $n \ge 1$, 
$$a_n=a_0+ c+c(-\lambda) +c(-\lambda)^2 + c(-\lambda)^3 +\cdots +c(-\lambda)^{n-1}.$$
Apart from the term $a_0$ at the front, we can see that $a_n$ is the partial sum of a *geometric series* with first term $c$ and common ratio $-\lambda$.

We can now use the formula for the sum of a finite geometric series to get a simple formula for $a_n$, and then take the limit.

Or else we can see that by the *definition* of the sum of an infinite geometric series, we have
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=a_0+c\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-\lambda)^n.$$
When $|\lambda| <1$, the inner infinite series converges, and has sum $\frac{1}{1-(-\lambda)}$. It follows that 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=a_0+\frac{a_1-a_0}{1+\lambda}.$$

**Comment**: We describe an idea that would have made the proof much more attractive.  The geometry of the situation does not change if we *subtract* $a_0$ from $a_0$ and $a_1$.  The geometry of the situation also does not really change if we scale the interval from $0$ to $a_1-a_0$ by the factor $1/(a_1-a_0)$. Formally, let
$$b_k=\frac{a_k -a_0}{a_1-a_0}.$$
Then $b_0=0$, $b_1=1$, and the sequence $(b_n)$ satisfies the *same* recurrence as the sequence $(a_n)$.

The formulas become more attractive. We find that 
$$b_n=1-\lambda+\lambda^2-\lambda^3+ \cdots +(-1)^{n-1}\lambda^{n-1}=\frac{1-(-\lambda)^n}{1+\lambda},$$
so the sequence $(b_n)$ has limit $\frac{1}{1+\lambda}$.
Now use the fact that $b_n=\frac{a_n -a_0}{a_1-a_0}$ to find the limit of the sequence $(a_n)$.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to give an easy answer to this question.

So, It is given , $\alpha=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \implies \lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n-1}=\alpha$            (*)

And , $a_n=(1-\lambda)a_{n-1}+\lambda a_{n-2}$ , we can write it as $a_n+\lambda a_{n-1}=a_{n-1} +\lambda a_{n-2}$ $\forall n\ge 2$

Now, let  $ A_n=a_n+\lambda a_{n-1}$ and $A_{n-1}=a_{n-1} +\lambda a_{n-2}$ .

Note that $A_n=A_{n-1}=A_{n-2}=...=A_3=A_2$

$\implies$  $a_n+\lambda a_{n-1}=a_1+\lambda a_0$

After taking limit , we'll get $\alpha+\lambda \alpha=a_1+\lambda a_0$ (from *)

Hence , $\alpha=\frac{a_1+\lambda a_0}{1+\lambda}$ .