# what is the proper notation to express an dependant recursive formula and can one be solved

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, notation, problem-solving, fibonacci-numbers

Given a sequence of numbers, https://oeis.org/A001906

> [0, 1, 3, 8, 21, 55, 144, 377]

What would be the proper mathematical way to define this number set, and how would it be resolved explicitly from scratch?

The keen eyed among you may have already noticed that this is every other sequence from the Fibonacci sequence.
As such there is a recursive part (The Fibonacci sequence), http://oeis.org/A000045

```
F(0) = 0
F(1) = 1
F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)
```

more over there is a sub pattern in this case ever 2nd number of the sequence.
http://oeis.org/A005843

```
Xn = 2n
```

How does one derive the recursive formula for F2n, where Fn is the nth Fibonacci number as F(n) = F(2n-1) + F(2n-2) would surely fail

Finally the Fibonacci sequence can be explicitly solved with Binet's formula

```
F_n = int((  (1 + sqrt5) ** n - (1 - sqrt5) ** n ) / ( 2 ** n * sqrt5))
```

How would a test be performed to find out if it is feasible to solve such a sequence, and if so what method from first principles would be applied in order to solve?

I'm particularly interested in how such solutions are derived.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$ to format math.

Comment: [OEIS A001906](https://oeis.org/A001906)

Comment: The recurrence here is $a_n=3a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$.

Comment: Rob Pratt's comment was your answer. The site gives the recurrence as Angina Seng wrote it. Why did you just add the hyperlinks? The first question is answered.

Comment: Because I'm still not sure how that formula was derived other than finding it on that hyperlink, and while I do want to stand on the shoulders of giants, I would like to know their methodology not just their results

Comment: Then you need to reword your question from "How would such a pattern be described, as F(n) = F(2n-1) + F(2n-2) would surely fail" to "How does one derive the recursive formula for $F_{2n}$, where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number?"

Comment: And as you pointed out, we have an explicit formula for the Fibonacci sequence. Take that formula and replace each instance of $n$ with $2n$. That is the explicit formula.

Comment: This is true i could just use 2n but would make me no clearer as to the methodology that would have resulted in Binet's formula, when googling such a question many proofs are shown but few derivations, from first principles, only ones that start at points that cannot be clearly derived without prior knowledge of the solution

Comment: Are you asking how to [derive formulas for recursive functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/20942/26369) like Binet's formulas? Well these types of recurrences are called "linear recurrences" and a fairly general method is shown in many textbooks, as well as class notes like [these slides](http://nms.lu.lv/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/21-linear-recurrences.pdf), [this PDF](https://math.berkeley.edu/~arash/55/8_2.pdf), and [this Brilliant.org wiki page](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linear-recurrence-relations/).